# Null Reference exception when accessing variable from different script in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I keep getting a Null Reference Exception I've googled and looked for solutions but I just can't find exactly what is wrong here. The exact error that I get is **"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
RayCastCollect.Update () (at Assets/RayCastCollect.js:47)"**

What I am trying to do is do a RayCast and hit a the game object and make it disappear. That part is working fine. But after that I also want my inventory to be updated that is the part that is not working and that particular line of code produces the error. **player.GetComponent(Inv).cookedFish += 1;**

This is the code for the RayCast class

```
    #pragma strict

var rayLength : int = 10;

private var inventory : Inv;

private var guiShow : boolean = false;

var bush : GameObject;

var player : GameObject;
var berr:int;

function Start()
{
    inventory = GameObject.Find("First Person Controller").GetComponent(Inv);
}

function Update()
{
    var hit : RaycastHit;
    var fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);

    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, hit, rayLength))
    {
        if(hit.collider.gameObject.name == "log")
        {           
            guiShow = true;

            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
            {
                //inventory.wood++;
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
                guiShow = false;
                inventory.wood++;
            }
        }
        if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "BushFull")
        {
            guiShow = true;
            bush = (hit.collider.gameObject);

            if(Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
            {
                bush.GetComponent(BushController).berriesTaken = true;
                guiShow = false;
                player.GetComponent(Inv).cookedFish += 1;

            }
        }
            else
            {
                guiShow = false;
            }
    }
}


    function OnGUI()
    {
        if(guiShow == true)
        {
            GUI.Box(Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 150, Screen.height / 2 - 150, 100, 20), "PICKUP!");
        }
    }
```

And this is my Inventory class

```
var menuSkin : GUISkin;

var wood : int = 0;
var stone : int = 0;
var clay : int = 0;

var fish : int = 0;
public var cookedFish : int = 0;

var bottle : int = 0;
var bottledWater : int = 0;

var bandage : int = 0;

var minimumVal : int = 0;

private var showGUI : boolean = false;//to switch inventory on or off jo key press krne se hoga

private var playerGUI : PlayerGUI;

function Start()
{
    playerGUI = GameObject.Find("First Person Controller").GetComponent(PlayerGUI); 
}

function Update()
{
    if(wood <= 0)
    {
        wood = minimumVal;
    }

    if(stone <= 0)
    {
        stone = minimumVal;
    }

    if(clay <= 0)
    {
        clay = minimumVal;
    }

    if(fish <= 0)
    {
        fish = minimumVal;
    }

    if(cookedFish <= 0)
    {
        cookedFish = minimumVal;
    }

    if(bottle <= 0)
    {
        bottle = minimumVal;
    }

    if(bottledWater <= 0)
    {
        bottledWater = minimumVal;
    }

    if(bandage <= 0)
    {
        bandage = minimumVal;
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyDown("i")) //key 'i' press kro to agr on ha inv to off hjae and vice versa
    {
        showGUI = !showGUI;
    }

    if(showGUI == true)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0; //game pause hjaegi kind of sb kch ruk jaega
        GameObject.Find("First Person Controller").GetComponent(FPSInputController).enabled = false;//first person controls disable
        GameObject.Find("First Person Controller").GetComponent(MouseLook).enabled = false;//mouse control player k disabled
        GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent(MouseLook).enabled = false;
        GameObject.Find("FPSArms_Axe@Idle").GetComponent(PlayerAnimation).enabled = false;
        //GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent(RayCastCollect).enabled = false;
    }

    if(showGUI == false)
    {//agr inv ni khuli hwi to baki jo upr false ki hain unhe wapis true krdo
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        GameObject.Find("First Person Controller").GetComponent(FPSInputController).enabled = true;
        GameObject.Find("First Person Controller").GetComponent(MouseLook).enabled = true;
        GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent(MouseLook).enabled = true;
        GameObject.Find("FPSArms_Axe@Idle").GetComponent(PlayerAnimation).enabled = true;
    //  GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent(RayCastCollect).enabled = true;
    }
}

function OnGUI()
{
    if(showGUI == true)
    {//inv menu ki gui sari bn ri ha idhr
        GUI.skin = menuSkin;
            GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 150, Screen.height / 2 - 150, 300, 300));
                GUI.Box(Rect(0, 0, 300, 300), "Basic Inventory");

                //Resources collected
                GUI.Label(Rect(10, 50, 50, 50), "Wood");
                GUI.Box(Rect(60, 50, 20, 20), "" + wood);

                GUI.Label(Rect(90, 50, 50, 50), "Stone");
                GUI.Box(Rect(130, 50, 20, 20), "" + stone);

                GUI.Label(Rect(170, 50, 50, 50), "Clay");
                GUI.Box(Rect(200, 50, 20, 20), "" + clay);


                //Empty holders
                GUI.Label(Rect(10, 130, 50, 50), "Fish");
                GUI.Box(Rect(60, 130, 20, 20), "" + fish);

                GUI.Label(Rect(10, 150, 50, 50), "Bottle");
                GUI.Box(Rect(60, 150, 20, 20), "" + bottle);

                //Edible items
                GUI.Label(Rect(10, 190, 50, 50), "CFish");//label
                GUI.Box(Rect(60, 190, 20, 20), "" + cookedFish);//text box type thingy
                if(GUI.Button(Rect(100, 190, 100, 20), "Eat Fish"))//button bn ra ha
                {
                    if(cookedFish >= 1)
                    {
                        cookedFish--;
                        Eat();
                    }
                }

                GUI.Label(Rect(10, 210, 50, 50), "BWater");
                GUI.Box(Rect(60, 210, 20, 20), "" + bottledWater);
                if(GUI.Button(Rect(100, 210, 100, 20), "Drink Water"))
                {
                    if(bottledWater >= 1)
                    {
                        bottledWater--;
                        Drink();
                    }
                }

                GUI.Label(Rect(10, 240, 50, 50), "Heal");
                GUI.Box(Rect(60, 240, 20, 20), "" + bandage);
                if(GUI.Button(Rect(100, 240, 100, 20), "Use Bandage"))
                {
                    if(bandage >= 1)
                    {
                        bandage--;
                        Heal();
                    }
                }
                GUI.EndGroup();
    }
}

function Eat()
{
    playerGUI.hungerBarDisplay += 0.1;
}

function Drink()
{
    playerGUI.thirstBarDisplay += 0.1;
}

function Heal()
{
    playerGUI.healthBarDisplay += 0.1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is either because the player object is null, either because it doesn't have the Inv script attached to it. As I see, you do not set the value of the player inside your script, so check if it is assigned in Editor, and that the assigned gameobject has an inv script attahced to it. To avoid this error you might try checking for null before assigning the value, replace:

```
player.GetComponent(Inv).cookedFish += 1;
```

with

```
if(player != null && player.GetComponent(Inv)!= null){
 player.GetComponent(Inv).cookedFish += 1;
}
```